# portions of plot missing for a relatively simple function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to produce a graph of the linear dynamic system response to a step input.

The code is as follows:

```
    ssm=StateSpaceModel[{
      8*x''[t] + 0.1*x'[t] + 0.64*k*(0.64*x[t] - y[t]) == u[t],
      25*y''[t] + 0.08*y'[t] + k*(y[t] - 0.64*x[t]) == 0},
      {{x'[t],0}, {x[t],0}, {y'[t],0}, {y[t],0}}, 
      {{u[t],0}}, {y'[t]}, t]; 
    klist = {5, 100, 350, 750};
    result = Table[OutputResponse[ssm /. k -> i,
         100 UnitStep[t], t], {i, klist}];
    TableForm[Partition[Table[Plot[result[[i]], {t, 0, 1000},
        PlotLabel -> ("k =" <> ToString[klist[[i]]])], {i, 1, 4}], 2]]
```

For some reason portions of 3 plots are missing, as shown in the figure:
[image]

How can I fix that so that plots are displayed in their entirety?

Note: In Mathematica 10.3.1 these very plots were generated in full with no problem. Now, when i upgraded to 10.4 this problem has surfaced.

thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the FullForm of your variable `result` you will see that it contains some small complex numbers. You can remove these by using `Plot[Abs[result[[i]]]` instead.

Comment: Or just use [Chop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html), i.e., `Plot[result[[i]] // Chop, ...`